# golang grammar questions about struct

Tags: go

here is some codes, but it is so long and unnecessary.
Sometimes I need to write somethings to mysql,
there is some kind of tables like that.

I have been try to use interface{}, but it is more complex.

Is there any way to make it shorter?

```
type One struct{
    Id int
    Name String
    Status bool
    Devtype string
    ...
    Created time.Time
}

type Two struct{
    Id int
    Name String
    Status bool
    Devtype string
    ...
    Created time.Time
}

type Three struct{
    Id int
    Name String
    Status bool
    Devtype string
    ...
    Created time.Time
}

func Insert(devtype string){
    if devtype == "one"{
        var value One
        value.Id = 1
        value.Name = "device"
        value.Status = false
        value.Devtype = devtype //only here is different
        value.Created = time.Now()
        fmt.Println(value)
    }else if devtype == "two"{
        var value Two
        value.Id = 1
        value.Name = "device"
        value.Status = false
        value.Devtype = devtype //only here is different
        value.Created = time.Now()
        fmt.Println(value)
    }else if devtype == "three"{
        var value Three
        value.Id = 1
        value.Name = "device"
        value.Status = false
        value.Devtype = devtype //only here is different
        value.Created = time.Now()
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

golang's struct inherit will help this

```
type Base struct {
    Id int
    Name String
    Status bool
    ...
    Created time.Time
}

type One struct{
    Base
    Devtype string
}

type Two struct{
    Base
    Devtype string
}

type Three struct{
    Base
    Devtype string
}

func Insert(devtype string, base Base){
    switch devtype {
        case "one"
            var value One
            value.Base = base
            value.Devtype = devtype //only here is different
        case "two"
            var value Two
            value.Base = base
            value.Devtype = devtype //only here is different
        case "three"
            var value Three
            value.Base = base
            value.Devtype = devtype //only here is different
    }
}
```

PS: since there is noly one field different, it is not a good practice to create three type